# Deneb scatterplot with a vertical line based on a dynamic value

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot, deneb

```html
{  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
    "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Datum", 
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
      "type": "nominal", 
      "title": "ProductieDatum",
      "axis": {
        "labelExpr":"[timeFormat(datum.value,'%d'),timeFormat(datum.value,'%b'),timeFormat(datum.value,'20%y')]"}
    },
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "Trendanalyse"}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "size": 3.0,
      "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "uitslag_trend_log10", "title": "KVE 10 log"},
          "color": {
            "field": "UitslagType",
            "type": "nominal"
          }
      
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": {"expr": "pbiColor(3)"}, "size": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
            "aggregate": "average",
            "field":  "uitslag_trend_log10", "title": "Gemiddelde"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am making a Deneb visual in Power Bi. I have a scatterplot with an average line. Now I want to add a vertical line based on a value that the user can select in a parameter field. In the custom scatterplot of Power BI i can add a trend line based on a field value. Is this possible with Deneb?

When I add the parameter field in my Deneb visual I get to many rows in my selection. It doesn't work.
Is it possible to add a dynamic vertical line to my visual?
This is my JSON code

Comment: Can you supply a spec with data or a sample .pbix with your code?

Comment: I added the JSON script

Comment: Thanks but we need data to go with it. Either create data inline so we can test in the editor or upload your .pbix to an external site and share a link.

Comment: I can't share the data because it's confidential. But I have been thinking. I can put the values in a table and add the table to Power BI. And let the customer choose the value in a slicer and add that field to my Deneb. I am going to try this.

Comment: If you don't solve it, try and create a minimum reproducible example you can upload and share.

Comment: This problem is solved, I made a table with the values and I added this to my report as a slicer. the value of the slicer is added to my deneb visual